# Add random product to cart, try to order

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, uipath

Let's say that I have random list of shops. For each of this shop I need to find random product (based on button "add to cart" for example), then navigate to cart, put my first/last name, e-mail etc. and try to order product without buying it (I just need to see what kind of delivery methods are avaliable to choose).
Problems:

- Shops doesn't have the same UI
- Shops doesn't work on the same "engine"
- Some shops have multipages (shop 1 -> find random product -> add to cart -> go to cart -> order -> fill 5 fields -> get delivery methods, shop 2 -> find random product -> add to cart -> click order -> click create account -> fill 10 fields -> get delivery methods)

In your opinion, is it even possible to do? For now I'm trying webscrapping, UIPath, learning more about webcrawler. What in your opinion would be best methods to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

what are you asking exactly? is it possible to write 1 code module to work with any of the sites? No, as UiPath recognition is based on UI, so for each UI you'll need to create separate sequence. you may split the whole flow into actions (for example, navigate, find product etc) where you accept element selectors/paths as arguments and reuse some of the workflows several times. it makes sense to create a separate workflow for some action if it's repeated many times in the same or very similar way and if this action is represented by several steps - I mean it doesn't make sense to create a modular workflow for input username as far as it is just one activity. but in general, as far as UiPath depends on the UI, I believe you'll need to code most of the shops separately.